# Error while assigning the function to void pointer list in SWIFT 3?

Tags: c, swift3, void-pointers

Recently started coding in Swift 3.0 and Xcode-8.0
facing issue to assign swift class function address to void pointer list which defined in structure

**file.h**

```
typedef struct MYStruct
{
    void ** funptr;   //The list of function pointer addr 
    size_t  funCount;  

}   MYStruct;
```

**file1.swift**

```
.....
func Dummy()
{

}

func utility()
{
    var myStructObj = MYStruct()

    myStructObj.funptr = &Dummy() //Error: Cannot assign value of type '() -> Int32' to type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>!'

    ......
```

//need to pass this struct to C function, in the C function it will call the deferred function to execute

```
  cfunc(&myStructObj);
......

}
```

Please suggest me to resolve, Thanks in-advance

Answer (score 0):

As understood from swift language, we can't get the function address directly by deference like how we do in 'C'

In swift, only way to get the function address by symbol, once you build the program, use **`objdump` or `nm`** to get the symbols of the function  which you need to pass to `C` call routines as function pointers

It's completely manual process. I'm able to achieve in this way.